# Perl Regex for number count R-lang

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am using R and New to regex:
I need a regex to extract the 'statuses_count' for a json-like text. Data is organized into a dataframe, with text in each row. sample data row:

```
{'lang': u'en', 'profile_background_tile': False, 'statuses_count': 4414, 'description': u'Progessive,interested in the psychology of politics.
```

result should be: 4414.

I was thinking of using str_extract_all with the perl option, but I don't understand how to grab only the number following the 'statuses_count'
    (?<=statuses_count.:)(something)

As a newbie, it would be great to understand how to say 'grab the number after 'statusescount.' Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be better to use `RJSONIO` or `jsonlite` libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I am using `perl` regex as per the title of the post.

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract_all(str1, perl("(?<=statuses_count': )\\d+"))[[1]]
#[1] "4414"
```

Visualize

```
(?<=statuses_count': )\\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AB_4nbfIW1W28sMq)

Or using `stringi` (faster for big datasets)

```
 library(stringi)
  stri_extract_all_regex(str1, "(?<=statuses_count': )\\d+")[[1]]
 #[1] "4414"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "{'lang': u'en', 'profile_background_tile': False, 'statuses_count': 4414, 'description': u'Progessive,interested in the psychology of politics."
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) sub**.  Simple solution with no packages.

```
sub(".*'statuses_count': (\\d+).*", "\\1", x)
## [1] "4414"
```

Visualization of regular expression:

```
.*'statuses_count': (\d+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/G9FIH62x-Ufm4P9Y)

**2) gsub** If we know that there are no other digits in the string (as is the case in the example) its even easier as we can just remove non-digits:

```
gsub("\\D", "", x)
## [1] "4414"
```

Visualization of regular expression:

```
\D
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iJoDsD87eUcit_KH)

**3) strapply or straplyc** This approach involves a relatively simple regex:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "'statuses_count': (\\d+)", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "4414"
```

or if you want a numeric output:

```
strapply(x, "'statuses_count': (\\d+)", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 4414
```

Visualization of regular expression:

```
'statuses_count': (\d+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6vkd3BszjCsnZJtK)

**Note::** None of these require Perl regex extensions.  Ordinary regexes will work.